# Convert a data frame or events into frequency

Tags: r, reshape, melt

```
testData <- data.frame("player" = c(1,2,1,2,2,3,3,2,3,1),
                    "event" = c(rep("shot",3),rep("pass",5),rep("score",2)))

testData
#   player event
#1       1  shot
#2       2  shot
#3       1  shot
#4       2  pass
#5       2  pass
#6       3  pass
#7       3  pass
#8       2  pass
#9       3 score
#10      1 score


desiredResult

#  player shots passes scores
#1      1     2      0      1
#2      2     1      3      0
#3      3     0      2      1
```

Comment: `table(testData)` or `table(testData$player, testData$event)` if you have other columns